# Fragment not being removed from back stack

Tags: android

I've noticed a strange behaviour when not adding a framgent transaction to the back stack. I have 4 fragments: A, B, C and D. The transaction for the C fragment isn't added to the back stack. First I add A, then B, then C. Then I press BACK. A is displayed,  which is normal. Then I add D and I press BACK. The result is that the fragment C is displayed. Is there something I am missing, because I would expect C to be out of the back stack and to see fragment A.

Answer (score 0):

> The transaction for the C fragment isn't added to the back stack.

ok.

> First I add A, then B, then C. Then I press BACK. A is displayed,

If you have added B to the backstack, it should display B and not A.

> Then I add D and I press BACK.

If you have not added C, then it should show B and not C. If it is showing C that means that you have added C to the backstack.

> Is there something I am missing.

From my understanding of the situation, you **have not** added B to the backstack and you **have** added C to the backstack.

Comment: "First I add A, then B, then C. Then I press BACK. A is displayed" This is normal. When I press back, it will display the previous fragment related to the current in the back stack. The current is B, so the previous is A.

Comment: When you click the `Back`, popBackStack is executed which pulls the top state off the backstack. I thought/still think that B will be in the top of the Backstack when C is running. May be my understanding is wrong. Anyhow, I'm curious to know whats the right way.

Comment: Use this example: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentStack.html. Edit the addFragmentToStack method and don't add the fourth fragment to the stack. Then play back an forward.